# How Android onActivityForResult reacts toggling app between foregrnd AND bckgrnd?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Consider this scenario:

```
public class Parent extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate();
.......
}

  public void onResume(){
       super.onResume();
     ....
    onClick of BUTTON b1.....

        Intent intent = new Intent(Parent.this, Child.class);
    intent.putExtra("param", data);
     startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_LAUNCH_CHILD_ACTIVITY);
     }

      ....
   }

  public void onActivityResult(){
    do something......
   }
 }
}
```

==========================================

```
public class Child extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate();
.......
}

  public void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     setResult(OK);
     finsh();
     }

      ....
   }
 }
}
```

Steps:

1. Launch Parent activity.
2. Click Button b1 on Parent and launch child
3. Child is brought successfully and shows up on screen
4. Now hit Home Button on the Android device (hardware)
5. Child's onPause, onStop and onDestroy is called.

But I dont see the program control entering Parent's onActivityResult when app is brought to the backgrnd.

Where is the program control for this particular when app is in background status?

On bring app back to foregrnd what is the expected behavior in terms of activity life cycle?

Thanks in advance

Can anyone explain on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the call to finish() in onPause, then hitting the home key calls only the child activities onPause method. When you re-launch the app, only the child activities onResume method is called. None of the parent methods seem to be called. The pattern of calling setResult in the activity and then finish in onPause FAILS after the user changes the phone orientation. So if the user enters data, saves the data (calling setResult in onSaveButtonClicked), changes phone orientation, and exits calling finish and the changes ARE NOT SAVED.

Consider calling finish() immediately after setResult at the moment you have enough data to set the result, exiting the child activity.

```
// UPDATE BUTTON HANDLER
    final Button buttonUpdate= (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonPasswordUpdate);
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            String password= editTextPasswordFirst.getText().toString();
            String verify= editTextPasswordSecond.getText().toString();  
            String err="";

            if (password.equals(verify) && (password.length() >= minimumPasswordLength)) { // 1) SUCCESS
                ResetTimeoutValues(timeoutType); // new password so calculate new timeout time     
                isValidKey= true;
                PasswordState outPasswordState= new PasswordState(lengthKey,
                        timeExpire,
                        isValidKey,
                        timeoutType,
                        password,
                        isHashPassword,
                        minimumPasswordLength);
                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putSerializable("jalcomputing.confusetext.PasswordState", outPasswordState);
                getIntent().putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,getIntent());   // call home with data on success only
                finish(); // go back <=== EXITS Here
                return;
            }...
    });
```

Comment: Hi Jal, Thanks for the explanation. As per my req I dont need to return or save any data back to the Parent activity. The purpose is When user is in child activity .. app is brought to bckgrnd.... the next time the app is brought back to foregrnd I dont want my child activity to show up... I want see my parent activity. This is the req.   Is there any better way to do this flow other using startActivityForResult ??

Comment: @Akh Without knowing your exact requirements I can only guess. Why not launch the child activity in onCreate, say only after a hard kill, and call finish in ChildActivity.onPause? This would meet the requirements for say a splash screen that goes away when the user hits the Home key, but returns if the user hits the back key twice.

Comment: hi Jal, Sorry I didnt get your point clearly. If you dont mind can you elaborate on this please.

Comment: @Akh  If you do not need to return data from child Activity to Parent Activity you can just call startActivity in the Parent Activity button.onClick and call finish in ChildActivity.onPause. IF you do this, what requirement is not met?

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you. Jal a different question. If an app is brought to the background waht happens to the UI Thread which was running this app? Will sleep or killed? When app back to foreground will the same thread be notified or a new thread will created and associated with the app instance?

Comment: @Akh The answer seems to be "it depends". Here is a link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html "A process holding an activity that's not currently visible to the user (the activity's onStop() method has been called). These processes have no direct impact on the user experience, and the system can kill them at any time to reclaim memory for a foreground, visible, or service process."